# Stripe: what is the exact functionality of transfer_group?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am familiar with the documentation on Stripe's website about the `transfer_group` property here: [Transfer Options](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#transfer-options). However, I find this documentation rather limited and I'm still not sure what it does exactly.

One of the things that I'd expect to happen, is that the charge and associated transfer(s) are somehow grouped together on the Stripe Dashboard. But this appears to not be the case.

My question thus is, what does the `transfer_group` property do exactly and why would one use it?

EDIT:
I found some use for it now. It can be used in the following way:

```
const transfers = await stripe.transfers.list({
    transfer_group: bookingId
})
```

This returns all the `transfers` associated with that `transfer_group`. Their id's can then be used to create `transfer_reversals` for example.

Note that the reason I'm not considering this finding as an answer, is because there must be more to it to this (I think).

Answer (score 0):

It associates Charges with Transfers for use in [Separate Charges and Transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers).

Comment: As I said in my question, I am familiar with the documentation at that link. I'm just not sure what the point is of having `charges` associated with `transfers`. For example, the Stripe dashboard does not appear to be grouping them in any sort of meaningful way

Comment: I'd reach out to Support to ask about this: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Comment: @Marnix.hoh did you find out what is its purpose?

Comment: @Luccas please see my edits to my answer. I hope it helps you

Comment: This helps when you create transfers associated with charges. When you have the transfer group defined, the transfer will occur when the associated charge is completed. If not, the transfer will occur using the available stripe balance, and if the balance is not enough, it will fail.

Comment: Mahesh I believe this is incorrect. From Stripe docs: `The transfer_group only identifies associated objects. It doesn’t affect any standard functionality. To prevent a transfer from executing before the funds from the associated charge are available, use the transfer’s source_transaction attribute.`